# Should I upgrade from Apache 1.3.x to 2.x?

Tags: apache

We are in the middle of setting up a new container to migrate our ever growing web app onto. Primarily to satisfy a security audit, but also to catch up and implement missing/outdated security.

The new container currently has Apache 1.3.42 installed, which is the same as what the original container is currently running. Should I be trying to upgrade Apache to 2.x during this process? And am I likely to run into some problems with missing modules.

Comparisons turned up in Google are all outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any definitive answer is going to require specific information about your app(not appropriate here; can get your question closed as too localized), but unless there's some special reason/requirement for staying on 1.3, you should probably at least look into upgrading. If you're not using any particularly obscure modules it most likely won't be too painful.

You didn't link any examples for your comment about comparisons being outdated so that's hard to gauge, but part of the likely reason is that [Apache 1.3x was end-of-life'd](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-modperl/201002.mbox/%3C4B699288.2050005@utoronto.ca%3E) about two and a half years ago, so the topic's largely closed by now. At that point, 2.x was already 8+ years old, so it's not like it'd be terribly unstable, etc. I know that early on 1.3 had some performance advantages and that was a common reason for people to stick with it, but 2.x has improved since and I'd put greater weight on 1.3 being a relative dead end.

Comment: Thankyou, I know it is a pretty general question and as such gets a general answer. We are not using any obscure modules, just the standard, mod_sec, mod_rewrite etc.